# Need to get data into Quickbooks

Tags: java, import, quickbooks

I'm looking for an existing Java (or JVM'able language) library that will create IIF files for import into Quickbooks.  Free or Commercial. Anyone know of something?

UPDATE:

After reading a comment on this question, I looked at the IPP and SDK options that Intuit provides and they could not have made this more difficult.  So here is what I need to do.  I need to take data from my database and export it into some sort of format that I can then import  into Quickbooks.  This doesn't really even need to be an automatic process as the Quickbooks application/database won't be on the server (linux) that the web applications runs on.

Comment: You know that IIF files are deprecated, offer very limited functionality, and often corrupt QuickBooks files, right? You should be using IPP/IDS or the SDK instead.

Comment: No Keith, I didn't know that.  Google led me to believe IIF files were it.  Do you have any links to that info? Specifically the SDK?

Comment: I found the QB web site with info on IPP/IDS and the SDK.  All I can say is that they couldn't have made it more difficult for what I need to do.  All I want to do is take data from my database and get it imported into Quickbooks.  The import is a manual process.  I'm going to update my question.

Comment: Yeah, welcome to QuickBooks. :-) Integration with QuickBooks is a pain in the butt.

Comment: Are you still looking for a Java solution (even if the solution lives on your Linux web server?)? i.e. Your web app is Java on Linux?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a number of free options as well if you're comfy rolling your own (or using Intuit test apps).

If you download the [QuickBooks SDK](http://qbsdk.developer.intuit.com/sdk/qb), it includes examples of sending QuickBooks XML documents which instruct QuickBooks to add customers, add transactions, etc. etc. etc. The examples could *easily* be extended to allow you to copy/paste in an XML document or load an XML document from disk.

You could then build the actual XML files in Java. If you wanted to get really fancy, use [JAXB](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/index-140168.html) (or an equivalent XSD to Class generator) to generate Java classes from the included .XSD documents, and be able to do things like: InvoiceAdd inv = new InvoiceAdd();

There's documentation about the XML format included in the QuickBooks SDK. You can also find some [QuickBooks XML examples](http://wiki.consolibyte.com/wiki/doku.php/quickbooks_qbxml) on our [QuickBooks integration wiki](http://wiki.consolibyte.com/wiki/doku.php/quickbooks_example_qbxml).

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to use [QODBC](http://www.qodbc.com/) for this. According to the [QODBC newsgroup](http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/qodbc/msearch?query=jdbc&submit=Search&charset=ISO-8859-1), some people are using this QuickBooks database driver with JDBC.

Answer (score 2):

Just wanted to add to this because ive been looking into it recently.  (what a pita)

It seems there are some main choices:

1. Using the quickbooks SDK which means dealing with COM
2. Using one of the poorly implemented libraries available:

   - [/n Software QB Integrator](http://www.nsoftware.com/ibiz/quickbooks/) to connect and do transactions on QB object (Invoice, Customer).  You will need to run a little app while QB is open for this one called QBConnector.  There is very limited documentation for this.
   - [Dragon Quickbooks Java Connector](http://dragonpg.com/software/quickbooks/) which is a lower level connector for dealing with the XML responses for Quickbooks.  [qbXML](http://wiki.consolibyte.com/wiki/doku.php/quickbooks_qbxml)
3. Using an importer as listed above which really means you have to still do an external step although it can be batched.
4. [QODBC](http://www.qodbc.com/qodbc.htm) as mentioned above which is what I am probably going to go with.  You can read and write (but not to all tables) with this.  [Full QB Table schema for US version](http://doc.qodbc.com/qodbc/20/tables/table_info_all_us.html)

I am very surprised at the extremely poor support Intuit is giving small business for integrating their software with QB.  If any COM devs are out there that want to design a nice java library I am sure there are lots of small business out there that would happily pay for a well designed one.  (More intelligent access mechanism and search ability)

Good luck to all your brave QB Spelunkers.

Answer (score 2):

Last but not least CoreObjX is a popular QuickBooks API wrapper for development (faster than QODBC) and OpenSync is an effortless QuickBooks data replication engine.

http://synergration.com/software/coreobjx
http://synergration.com/software/opensync

Answer (score 1):

There are several companies offering transactional importing in QuickBooks:

- http://www.qbalance.com/Import_transactions_into_QuickBooks.htm
- http://www.zed-systems.com/products/axis.aspx
- http://www.baystateconsulting.com/products/01TxnWizard.htm

I have not used any of these - so do your due diligence.

Comment: Thanks Doug.  I ran across this as well..http://www.uidev.simplebsinc.biz/osc/index.php

Answer (score 0):

This is another good option.
[JQBConnector](http://dragonpg.com/)

It generates QBXML from POJO's, so it makes manipulating the quickbooks format super easy.
It also can connect directly to quickbooks to send and retrieve information.