# Quickbooks integration with java API

Tags: java, linux, quickbooks, quickbooks-online, intuit-partner-platform

Well, i am looking to integrate `Quickbooks` with a java application. So far, i have read documents and articles relating to `QuickBooks` integration with java. However, i want to my java application to be developed in Linux system. I am new to `QuickBooks` and didn't find any supportive clue that it can be done in Linux system. My java app should be able to import and export novices to `QuickBooks online`. Does anyone have any idea from where i should start? is there any support for linux system?

Comment: sorry to tell you - I also tried to integrate quickbooks with a java application. The APIs provided doesn't do much. You better contact Quickbooks and see if it's possible now.

Answer (score 3):

First there are 2 ways to integrate with QuickBooks.

1. The QuickBooks SDK which communicates to QuickBooks via QBXML on the desktop. This is downloaded to the client and your app uses the SDK to read/write data. There are thousands of applications using this method. https://ipp.developer.intuit.com/0085_QuickBooks_Windows_SDK
   including Java.
2. Using the Intuit Partner Platform REST Api, which language you use is irrelevant.
   https://ipp.developer.intuit.com/0010_Intuit_Partner_Platform/0025_Intuit_Anywhere
   In fact there is a Java SDK which wraps these APIs to simplify the dev experience.
   SDK here: https://ipp.developer.intuit.com/0010_Intuit_Partner_Platform/0200_DevKits_for_Intuit_Partner_Platform/0200_IPP_Java_DevKit

There are pros and cons to each method. #1 has a poor customer experience because you need to download the app to the client, and keep the data in sync with QuickBooks.

method 2 via IPP takes care of the sync for you, but you need to build it as a SaaS application using REST APIs and there is a cost.

hope that helps

Jarred

Comment: For the SDK, here's some working sample code and a walk-through of how to get set up: http://wiki.consolibyte.com/wiki/doku.php/quickbooks_integration_java and http://wiki.consolibyte.com/wiki/doku.php/quickbooks_online_edition#connecting_with_the_desktop_model_of_communication

Comment: Also, just again emphasizing Jarred's point - if you're a SaaS application, DO NOT use the SDK - the SDK is terrible for QuickBooks Online (for QuickBooks desktop versions the SDK is much better). Instead, if you're a SaaS app use the Intuit Partner Platform APIs.

Comment: All links are broken. Can you please provide the new links.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a link to the Java solution that I posted last year to Intuit.

https://idnforums.intuit.com/messageview.aspx?catid=56&threadid=16655

It provides the steps you need to take.  Basically, you need to create a webservice that will be called by QBWC (quickbooks webconnector).  This allows QB to call your application to get the next request, etc.

There's a lot to it, but it ends up being a good solution.

Good luck.

Comment: That link is dead. Can you please add another

Answer (score 0):

My first hint for you is to download QuickBooks SDK and try out integrating it with Java. You should check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4797784/need-to-get-data-into-quickbooks) as well. Plus there is also a issue in getting QuickBooks online working on Linux. Check this [forum thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1098175) for that.

As I mentioned before I tried to integrate Quickbooks into a Java SE app but it didn't go smoothly since the API documentation was weak. I hope you will find a way to integrate Quickbooks online with you java app. Hope it helps..